# How can update the week timing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to update my shop timing in a week. I want to update the day, start time and end time of my shop. But it works differently. There is some problem in my update query. How can I convert it to Codeigniter? Is there any problem in my code? Any help would be appreciated.

**View page:**

```
<?
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($shop_timing->result() as $name) { 
?>
<br>
<input type="hidden" id="shop_time_id" name="time<?echo $i;?>" value="<?echo $name->shop_time_id;?>">
<select class="right" data-placeholder="select your category" id="day" data-rel="chosen" name="day<?echo $i;?>" >
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Monday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?> >Monday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Tuesday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Tuesday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Wednesday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Wednesday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Thursday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Thursday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Friday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Friday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Saturday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Saturday</option>
    <option <?php if($name->working_day=="Sunday"){?> selected="selected" <?}?>>Sunday</option>
    <!-- <option <?php if($name->shop_id==$name->shop_id) {?> selected="selected" <? } ?> ></option>                                                                                                                                                                -->
</select>
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <input type="text" class="timepicker starttime" value="<?echo $name->working_start_time?>" name="timefrom<?echo $i;?>" id="timefrom" placeholder="time"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <div class="input-group">             
        <input type="text" class="timepicker end" value="<?echo $name->working_end_time?>" name="endtime<?echo $i;?>" id="endtime" placeholder="time"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<?
        $i++;
    }

    for ($j = 1; $j <= (7-$count); $j++) {
?>
<select class="right" data-placeholder="select your category" id="day" data-rel="chosen" name="day<?echo $i;?>">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Day</option>
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
    <option>Wednesday</option>
    <option>Thursday</option>
    <option>Friday</option>
    <option>Saturday</option>
    <option>Sunday</option>
</select>
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <div class="input-group">           
        <input type="text" class="timepicker starttime" name="timefrom<?echo $i;?>" id="starttime3" placeholder="time"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <div class="input-group">             
        <input type="text" class="timepicker end" name="endtime<?echo $j;?>" id="endtime3" placeholder="time"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<?
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
$count = $this->SM->get_count($id);
$j = 1;
$k = 1;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $day[$i] = $this->input->post('day' . $i);
    if ($day[$i] != "") {
        $start[$i] = $this->input->post('timefrom' . $i);
        $end[$i] = $this->input->post('endtime' . $i);  
        $tid[$i] = $this->input->post('time' . $i);
        $days[$j] ='update`cr_shop_timing` set `working_day`="' . $day[$i].'",`working_start_time`="' . $start[$i] . '", `working_end_time`="' . $end[$i] . '" WHERE shop_time_id="' . $tid[$i] . '"';
        if ($count < $j) {
            $day1 = $day[$i];
            $start1 = $start[$i];
            $end1 = $end[$i];

            $this->SM->newupdate($id, $day1, $start1, $end1);
        }  

        $j++;
        $k++;
    }
}

$this->SM->timingupdate($id, $days);
?>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
    public function newupdate($id, $day1, $start1, $end1)
        {
            $data = array(
                'shop_id' => $id,
                'working_day' => $day1,
                'working_start_time' => $start1,
                'working_end_time' => $end1
            );

            $this->db->insert('shop_timing', $data);
        }

    public function timingupdate($id, $days) 
        {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= count($days); $i++) {
                $this->db->query($days[$i]);
            }        
        }
?>
```